# Is there a BEM methodology in which I can build a header with many elements using only one div?

Tags: html, css, bem

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo_place_header></div>
  <div class="header__title-text>Learning how to learn</div>
  <div class="header__subtitle-text><a href="#" class="header__subtitle-link>about 20 words here</a></div>
  <div class="header__main-illustration></div>
  <div class="header__square-pic></div>
</header>
```

The header class is a flex container and has relative position. Most of the flex items require absolute positioning. My question is borne from one of my instructors saying not to put a div inside the header except for the one containing the header__square pic. I don't understand how else to proceed. I am very much a rookie and I apologize for my beginners question. I know this forum is full of experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Instructor probably wanted you to find more suitable HTML Elements to describe the meaning of the document since `<div>` elements are non-semantic we can instead use:

the `<h1>` element to  represent the main heading
the `<p>` element for the subheading
and an `<img>` element for the illustration or logo

Since the class attribute is a global attribute, we can change the opening and closing tags of the HTML elements and keep the BEM naming conventions of your code

```
<header class="header">
  <img class="header__logo"></img>
  <h1 class="header__title-text>Learning how to learn</h1>
  <p class="header__subtitle-text><a href="#" class="header__subtitle-link>about 20 words here</a></p>
  <img class="header__main-illustration></img>
  <div class="header__square-pic></div>
</header>
```

I would recommend going over the [basic concepts of HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics) and looking up the MDN HTML reference manual for [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) and [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

Comment: This makes most sense. One thing I would do differently is make the logo a link with the `<a>` anchor and somehow do the other `<img>` tag with another tag because `<img>` is supposed to be for content, and calling a `background-image: url()` in css is for background images. What you said totally got me on the right track though.